# Is my SSD failing?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I've started getting these messages intermittently (see below).  I got a whole lot of them several days ago, then they stopped.  They occurred again last night, and stopped after the last line below.

My /dev/sda is a Samsung 850 EVO Series 120GB SSD and is under warranty.  It still seems to be functioning normally.  How can I test this drive to prove that there is a fault (if there is one)?

More info: 
Gentoo Linux AMD64
Kernel 4.0.5

Messages below:

```
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x7fffffff SErr 0x0 action 0x0
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/08:00:88:61:06/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in\x0a         res 41/04:00:80:61:06/00:00:01:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (devi
ce error)
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/08:08:90:61:06/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq 4096 in\x0a         res 41/04:00:80:61:06/00:00:01:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (devi
ce error)
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/08:10:98:61:06/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq 4096 in\x0a         res 41/04:00:80:61:06/00:00:01:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (devi
ce error)

[...]

Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : 0xb [current] [descriptor]
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 ASC=0x0 ASCQ=0x0
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 01 06 61 88 00 00 08 00
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 17195400
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 Sense Key : 0xb [current] [descriptor]
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 ASC=0x0 ASCQ=0x0
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 01 06 61 90 00 00 08 00
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 17195408

[...]

Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 17195464
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 Sense Key : 0xb [current] [descriptor]
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 ASC=0x0 ASCQ=0x0
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 01 06 61 d0 00 00 08 00
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 17195472
Jul 21 03:52:05 myserver kernel: ata1: EH complete
```

Comment: Samsung has software to go through their firmware tests use that

Comment: Agree with using the samsung utilities. You may also be interested in `smartctl` which also has some S.M.A.R.T. reporting and testing features.

Comment: can also be a cable/connector issue.